# problemas en consulta mysql desde php

Tags: php, mysql

estoy haciendo una consulta desde php a mi base de datos en mysql, el problema que tengo es que no se por que los datos se repiten en la respuesta, aquí esta la imágen de la respuesta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ven, tanto el nombre como el id_organizacion se repiten para cada línea y no entiendo por que, hago la misma consulta desde phpmyadmin y ahí si se muestra todo bien.

aquí esta el codigo como guardo la respuesta de la consulta en una variable:

```
$idOrgsUsuarioModificador =  $app->consultar("SELECT organizacion.nombre 
                                              FROM membresia, organizacion 
       WHERE membresia.id_funcionario='{$_SESSION['id_funcionario_actual']}' 
       AND membresia.id_organizacion=organizacion.id_organizacion");
```

además quisiera saber como pudiera acceder a cada nombre y id_organizacion desde php, estaba probando con: `$idOrgsUsuarioModificador.nombre` y no funciona.

En la función consultar es donde hago la conexion y consulta a la base de datos usando PDO

aquí esta el codigo:

```
    function consultar($sql, $modo = PDO::FETCH_BOTH) {
        $data = array();
        try {
            $con = $this->conectar();
            $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $data[0] = true;
                while ($fila = $stmt->fetch($modo)) {
                    $data[] = $fila;
                }

                $stmt->closeCursor();
            } else {
                $data[0] = false;
                $data = array_merge($data, $stmt->errorInfo());
            }
            unset($stmt);
            unset($con);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $data[0] = false;
            $data[1] = $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  y pon el código donde obtienes los datos desde el recurso que devuelve la query. Si estás mandando esos datos al cliente, pon también la parte del cliente donde manejas la respuesta del servidor.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya lo coloqué.

Comment: No sé que estilo de `fetch` tienes en `$modo`, prueba a cambiarlo por esto y dinos qué pasa: `while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {`

Comment: disculpa, habia copiado mal la funcion, ya lo corregí, tiene $modo = PDO::FETCH_BOTH .

Comment: Correcto, tu error es que usas el modo `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` el cual crea un array numérico y otro asociativo, por tanto tienes los datos dos veces. Si cambias esta línea así no te repetirá los datos: **`function consultar($sql, $modo = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {`** ahí te creará solamente un arragle asociativo con los datos.

Comment: Cierto... y no habría alguna forma de transformar el array generado por FETCH_BOTH a uno como el que genera FETCH_ASSOC fuera de la función consultar? lo que sucede es que no quiero cambiar el FETCH_BOTH por FETCH_ASSOC en la función.

Comment: Lo puedes cambiar recorriendo el array y sacando los índices numéricos. Pero eso no tiene sentido, seria recargar el código haciéndole traer datos dos veces para luego seguir trabajando quitándolos. De hecho `BOTH` prácticamente no se usa, ¿por qué no quieres renunciar a él?

Comment: porque es un código que ya está hecho y no quiero cambiarlo, porque temo que eso afecte otras cosas que hagan uso de esa función, creo que tendré que crear otra funcion igua pero con FETCH_ASSOC. otra pregunta... para acceder a los valores de la consulta como sería? esta intentando con esto: $idOrgsUsuarioModificador.nombre y también con $idOrgsUsuarioModificador[0] pero no funciona.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103776/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-julianprog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## El problema

Estás teniendo los datos dos veces debido al estilo de fetch que tiene configurado en la variable `$modo`, el cual es `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`. Este estilo, [según el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php):

> `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` (predeterminado): devuelve un array indexado tanto por
>   nombre de columna, como numéricamente con índice de base 0 tal como
>   fue devuelto en el conjunto de resultados.

O sea, crea un array numérico con los datos y otro array asociativo con los datos.

## La solución

Puedes cambiar el modo a uno que te devuelva los datos una sola vez.

Si quieres los datos en forma de array asociativo:

```
function consultar($sql, $modo = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
      // resto del código 
}
```

O, si quieres los datos en forma de array numerado:

```
function consultar($sql, $modo = PDO::FETCH_NUM) {
      // resto del código 
}
```